# Can we store just a clause of a WHERE condition into a variable in SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis, where-clause, conditional-split

I want to change the clause of my where condition dynamically from the config file. So if I store the clause into a variable I can do it, I am not able to figure out how.... Need a solution for this
I tried a conditional split but it didn't work.

Comment: Look up "SSIS expressions"

Comment: Is this a where condition for a sql task? If so, put the sql script in a variable and append the variable with the where clause you want to use then execute the sql in the variable.